# what is the best way to load content to speed up chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

currenly I've this: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUgRF/)**

As you can see there are 5 buttons at the top, and when you hover them, beneath the buttons shows up a content window. The problem is that every 'content window' is loaded when you load the page. When there is a lot of content in it, loading can take a while. Because this is for a chrome extension, chrome waits until everything is loaded before opening the extension bubble.

How to prevent the long load time? I've tried to load the content using innerHTML after window is loaded (window.onload). But that still slows down the extension.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you must use Ajax.

Comment: it's for a chrome extension, so it's client-side